# Maximum IO Transfer Size in Linux Kernel 4.13.10

Tags: linux-kernel

I am unable to issue an IO with transfer size more than 131 KB in linux kernel 4.13.10.  The failure is observed from the block layer api **blk_rq_map_user** with error code EINVAL (22). Is there any limitation on maximum IO size?